# Confused how to iterate over this xpath

Tags: python, json, selenium, loops

I am iterating over a JSON file and pasting contents of it simultaneously on a text editor on a website.

```
incrementor = 1

for x in range(len(jsonL)):
    jsonL[x]["question"] = jsonL[x]["question"].strip()
    if incrementor//2 != 1:
        element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[contains(@title, "Rich Text Editor, 
        editor{incrementor}")]')
        element.send_keys(jsonL[x]["question"])
        incrementor += 1
```

In the next iteration, I want

```
element.send_keys(jsonL[x][choices[0]])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's  the `choices`? I think you need to improve your question by providing a minimal working example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I made progress!!! how do i close this question?

Comment: Since you managed to solve this yourself, you can [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) -- its good practice so that others can benefit too.